# Delete one item from array with matching keys

Tags: php, arrays, rowdeleting

I have an array

```
$array = ['f'=>'foo', 'f'=>'foo', 'f'=>'foo','g'=>'good'];
```

and I want to delete only one item from this array with matching key, like the following:

```
unset($array['f']);
```

However, this will delete the all items with this matching key 'f' and only one item will remain. Is there a way to do something like this, but apply it only to the first matching item in the array?

Comment: you have a syntax error, but besides this your last `f` will over write all of your other defined `f` items in your array already, so there is no need to delete the others.

Comment: You can't have the same key multiple times!

Comment: @Rizier123 ... you can, they just overwrite eachother

Comment: i have asked this because i am developing cart,
with 
this class Cart

`class Cart{
$totalqty, $totalPrice , $items 
}`

and i add the Products in $items 
showing 5 elements of id 7 
but if i delete one
this delete all

Comment: use the real code, and the real data, or we cant help

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have a syntax error.

```
$array=$array(['f'=>'foo', 'f'=>'foo', 'f'=>'foo','g'=>'good']);
```

You have an $ extra and [] extras, and you can't have a lots off records with the same key(because the last one will override the previously)... The correct way to define

```
$array= array('f'=> array('foo', 'foo2', 'foo3'), 'g'=>'good');
```

The values will be a new array inside de F key. And then you can remove only one record

```
unset($array['f'][0]);
```

now your arrays var_dump:

```
$array= array('f'=> array('foo2', 'foo3'), 'g'=>'good');
```

Comment: thanks for your assistance, 
when i was using this `unset($array['f'])` this was removing elements matching to that key, 
but now 
with `unset($array['f'][0])`

Comment: now with `unset($array['f'][0])` this is not deleting any element from the array

Comment: No problem @feci, if you want to delete other element from F you have to change the number... [0] for ex: $array['f'][1]

Comment: Then what to do now

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this by using this as per **cmorrissy** comment there will be only one item so that variable was showing me qty, i have to check if

`if($product[$id]['quantity']>1){ $product[$id]['quantity']--;}else{unset($product[$id]);}`

Answer (score 0):

if you var_dump($array); this would be the output

```
var_dump($array);
array(
    f => foo
    g => good
 )
```

since you have an array with the same index it will be displayed as one, and thats why it will be deleted